# Azure - Folders in 'Blobs storage' and Folders in 'File storage'

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

This may seem Naive, I understand that we can create folders in a blob, and these folders are still stored in a container. we can still do everything on these 'folders contained in blobs' that we typically do on folders in File storage.

We can still use these 'Folder/Directory structure in blob containers' just like we use 'Folder/Directory structure in File storage' than what is the significance of having a file storage?

I know there could be some places where File storage must be playing a significant role. I just want to know few of those use-cases.

Comment: Here's a useful comparison https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks

Comment: Blob storage can not be used like file storage, and folders are really just extended file names.

Answer (score 2):

You typically choose file storage over blob storage when you need an **SMB interface**. Examples are legacy applications that rely on a local file storage. I also know people who like to use file storage when working with containers.

The [comparison provided from Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607482/azure-folders-in-blobs-storage-and-folders-in-file-storage#comment92149067_52607482) explain the Scenarios.

Comment: Genuinely a right hit for this question. Thank you. It helped me connect various points together. Please do mention any more use cases in case it strikes your mind.